# jQuery(…).datepicker is not a function. no exact solution get during Googling

Tags: jquery, html

```
@model APT.FlexPay.WebRole.Models.Payment.FullPaymentViewModel
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Site2.cshtml";
 }

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />*@
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#ExpiryDate").datepicker();
      });
    </script>



  @using (Html.BeginForm("payByDebitCreditCard", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "payForm" }))
     {
       <div class="payCon">
       <label>Expiry Date(MMYY)</label>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ExpiryDate, new { @size = "4", @maxlength = "4" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ExpiryDate)
        </div>
      }
```

after gooling put there same question. please let me know why show this error: **TypeError:$(...).datepicker is not a function

$("#ExpiryDate").datepicker();**

Comment: i have edit it please have a look.

Comment: Have you checked your Network tab in console (Chrome tools / Firebug) to see if jQuery and jQuery UI are being loaded in correctly? Only thing I can think of (potentially a http/https clash).

Comment: Does your layout page contains some other version of jQuery?

Comment: Take a look at this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ (ViewSource)

Comment: @RajeshDhiman yes in layoutpagre `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_cassette/asset/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js?6fc3f594b98d8a5cd3a38186d9d266732cb7d8e0">`

Comment: That could be a reason. Try changing that to `jquery-1.9.1.js`.

Comment: i have change in layout. but effect same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give refrence of **jQuery,jQuery-ui.js and jQuery-ui.css**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

at the end of the html code. Datepicker working fine. Thank you all guys for help.